# ¿Cómo actualizar el valor de un array en PHP?

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo actualizar el valor de un array?
Tengo un array como el siguiente:

```html
Array ( [Sucursal1] => Array ( 
[SucursalNombre] => Sucursal1 
[Producto1] => 225
[Producto2] => 2250
[Producto3] => 22
[Producto4] => 40
[Producto5] => 20

)
[Sucursal2] => Array ( 
[SucursalNombre] => Sucursal2
[Producto1] => 100
[Producto2] => 250
[Producto3] => 221
[Producto4] => 404
[Producto5] => 202
))
```

Quiero Actualizar el valor de  [Producto1] => 50  para la [sucursal1]  es decir

```html
Array ( [Sucursal1] => Array ( 
[SucursalNombre] => Sucursal1 
[Producto1] => **50**
[Producto2] => 2250
[Producto3] => 22
[Producto4] => 40
[Producto5] => 20

)
[Sucursal2] => Array ( 
[SucursalNombre] => Sucursal2
[Producto1] => 100
[Producto2] => 250
[Producto3] => 221
[Producto4] => 404
[Producto5] => 202
))
```

Comment: tienes una variable que te almacena todo el array o son 2 ?

Comment: no digamos que el array es infinito pueden haber N cantidad de sucursales y N cantidad de productos  . pero los productos en las sucursales se repiten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes es el siguiente array multidimensional:

```
$arr = array(
    "Sucursal1" => array( 
        "SucursalNombre" => "Sucursal1",
        "Producto1" => 225,
        "Producto2" => 2250,
        "Producto3" => 22,
        "Producto4" => 40,
        "Producto5" => 20
    ),
    "Sucursal2" => array( 
        "SucursalNombre" => "Sucursal2",
        "Producto1" => 100,
        "Producto2" => 250,
        "Producto3" => 221,
        "Producto4" => 404,
        "Producto5" => 202
    )
);
```

Para hacer el cambio que quieres, tienes que acceder al índice del primer array y seguidamente a su índice cuyo valor vas a modificar:

```
//Actualizar el valor de [Producto1] => 50 para la [sucursal1]
$arr[ "Sucursal1" ][ "Producto1" ] = 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta que es un array de arrays, y digamos que lo tienes contenido en una variable llamada `$array`, lo primero que tendremos que hacer será acceder a la primera sucursal.

Para ello, podremos utilizar:

```
$sucursal1 = $array["Sucursal1"];
```

Una vez hecho esto, podremos obtener el valor de Producto1 de la siguiente manera:

```
$producto1 = $sucursal1["Producto1"];
```

De forma simplificada para acceder a este producto sería:

```
$array["Sucursal1"]["Producto1"];
```

Por lo tanto, para asignarle un nuevo valor podríamos hacer:

```
$array["Sucursal1"]["Producto1"] = 50;
```